# How do I export an object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

For example, I'm trying to export a TS object to get this JavaScript output:

```
const path = require('path'),
      rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..'),
      env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

let config = {
  development: {
    amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:15672",
    root: rootPath
    
  },
  test: {
    amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:5672",
    root: rootPath
  
  },
  production: {
    amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:5672",
    root: rootPath

  }
};
module.exports = config[env];
```

This is my TS, but it's not clear with exporting,

```
import path = require("path")
    
    const rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
    
    let config = {
      development: {
        amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:15672",
        root: rootPath
        
      },
      test: {
        amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:5672",
        root: rootPath
      
      },
      production: {
        amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:5672",
        root: rootPath
    
      }
    };

   /* this is the line i'm having problem how can i export config object*/
    // export config[env];
```

I've tried `export default config[env]` but its generated output isn't expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In ES6 you are allowed to export names using the export function, or for default you can export anything.
The `require` format goes like this:

```
let config = require('config')
```

And it takes the default export of config file.
In your case, you should do:

```
export default config[env]
```

If you want to use the export, you would do something like:

```
let Environment = config[env];
export {Environment}
```

The difference would be:

```
import EnvirmentNameWhatever from "./config"
```

to

```
import {Environment} from "./config"
```

- Note - when default exporting, you can use whatever name you like, while when just exporting, you have to use the exported name.

Answer (score 27):

Using the `export` keyword on the declarations to export should do the job, like this:

```
import path = require("path")

const rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')
export const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

export let config = {
    development: {
    amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:15672",
    root: rootPath

    },
    test: {
    amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:5672",
    root: rootPath

    },
    production: {
    amqpUrl: "amqp://localhost:5672",
    root: rootPath

    }
};
```

Comment: i need to export `config[env]`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Wouldn't adding `env` to the exported `config` object work? Am I missing something?