# import code from javascript file inside typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives', 'ui.router', 'app.sysSettings', 'app.globalConstants',
    'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngTouch', 'ngDialog', 'ngCookies']);
```

And I would like to reuse this variable ("app") inside my ts file.
My app.components.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeModule } from "@angular/upgrade/static";
import { app } from  '../../apps/login/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule,
              private app_private: app.name) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [this.app_private]);
  }
}
```

I imported import { app } from  '../../apps/login/app'; , then added "app" to constructor and trying to use it inside ngOnInit function but getting error :

```
compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: ([object Object], ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15706)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15541)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:15026)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:15854)
    at compiler.js:15335
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15335)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
```

Does anybody have suggestions how to make property from javascript file be accessible inside typescript class?

Comment: In order to make it accessible, your have to export it using `export const app = angular.module('app')`

Comment: I replaced var app = angular.module('app', to export const app = angular.module(' but have error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export". Do I need to add any library or declare "export" somewhere? Thanks

Comment: export is not yet fully supported, you have to do it from typescript, I'll provide an answer.

Comment: Answer is in how to export object in typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762570/how-to-export-object-in-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to import an object from a file, it has to be exported using the `export` keyword. However, your angularjs app is defined in normal javascript files outside typescript so using export is not an option. So, to have access to it from typescript, first you have to bring it to typescript level and then you will be able to import it from your component.

So you can create the following `ts` file to import the app to typescript:

**my-angularjs-app.ts**

```
let angular = window['angular'];  // to avoid typescript syntax error

export const app = angular.module('app');
```

**app.component.ts**

Then you can use it on your module like so:

```
import { app } from  'my-angularjs-app';

// ...

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [app.name]);
  }
}
```

> Notice, you don't have to inject it on the constructor, the value is already there.