# TypeScript - module.exports throws error TS2591: Cannot find name 'module'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a file called `config.ts` which contains following code:

```
let config = {
  foo: {
    bar: [{env: "test"}...],
    ...
    ...
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I'd like to use this file application-wide.

However, this code results in the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/configs/config.ts:357:1 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

357 module.exports = config;
```

I have checked that I have `@types/node` installed and `tsconfig.json` file contains `"types": ["node"]` under `compilerOptions`.

How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to export object in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762570/how-to-export-object-in-typescript):

Try `export default config` instead of `modules.exports = config`.