# Module export in typescript

Tags: typescript

What is the equivalent for this in typescript?

```js
module.exports = (app, passport) =>{
function ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I export an object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762570/how-do-i-export-an-object-in-typescript)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your module bunder, but if you use ES6 modules you could do this:

```
 export const test = (app:string, pass:string) => { 
     console.log(app, pass)
 }
```